# Throttling Redis Message Queue execution with service stack

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack, message-queue, quartz.net

I'd like to be able to throttle the level at which messages are executed so as to limit the load on my databases if there's a high volume of traffic on my site then the queue will concertina out and in time of low volume the queue will be processed.

Here's the use case.

A user makes a change to some data in our website which saves a new row of a data to a much larger object.  I then want to add a message to a queue to say that the larger object needs updated in our Search database.

A windows service on another machine reads messages off the queue in a throttled way. It will then pull the objects out of the SQL database in full, convert them to the search poco and then update that object in the search database.

I think I could either run a scheduled job which goes every x seconds which will read one off the queue and process it or go with some other mechanism of throttling.

I've included below my first kind of attempt which is untested (that's for tomorrow),

I'm programming in c# and using the service stack libraries with the job being executed by the quartz net scheduling library.

Perhaps there is a much better way to do this?

```
public class UpdateJob : IJob
{   
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var redisFactory = new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379");
        var mqHost = new RedisMqServer(redisFactory, retryCount: 2);

        mqHost.RegisterHandler<UpdateMessage>(m =>
        {
            // do the proper logic here.
            Console.WriteLine("Received: UpdateId [" + m.GetBody().Id + "]");
            return;
        });
        mqHost.Start();
    }
}
```

I'm also not massively bothered if a message gets lost now and again so persistence of the messages if redis crashes isn't an issue.  It's quick enough for me just to rebuild the whole Search database from scratch if that were to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need Quartz.net for this scenario. You can easily adapt the number of threads within your `RegisterHandler`-method call with the `noOfThreads`-parameter:

```
var redisFactory = new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379");
var mqHost = new RedisMqServer(redisFactory, retryCount: 2);

mqHost.RegisterHandler<UpdateMessage>(m =>
{
    // TODO processing happens here
}, 2);
mqHost.Start();
```

This will limit your degree of parallelism to 2, which can act as a perfect way of throtteling.